# These are (the) / (nothing) lobsters

Tags: grammar, articles

I was in my son's English class (beginner) and there was a picture of a lobsters on it. The teacher wanted the kids to form a correct sentence using 'lobster(s)'. A kid said:

"These are the lobsters."

Was it correct? I feel like it sounds a little bit off because I'd often hear:

"These are lobsters"

instead, unless it's:

"These are the lobsters that we caught this morning"

or something. I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to grammar, so I can only feel like it's off, but having no explanation whether or not it is wrong.

I'm not a native speaker, so kindly forgive me if my question is silly.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Both sentences are perfectly grammatical—and acceptable barring any limitations. I would assume it would be a sentence given in response to something like *Are those the lobsters?* If the teacher wanted to specify a sentence that was appropriate to a given context (even if the context is *a standalone sentence that doesn't require a previous statement*), then the context should also have been provided. Note that even *these are lobsters* has no meaning unless it's clear that something is being referenced when the sentence is stated. Somebody suddenly shouting it out in a car would be strange.

Comment: Either one. No article when identifying the type of animal, a definite article when referring to the group of lobsters on the page. Using *the* usually implies a restricted group of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right.

> These are lobsters.

is correct in this case.

The use of the *definite article "the"* would mean that you are talking about some specific lobsters, as you then describe in a later sentence:

> These are the lobsters that we caught this morning.

Note that the original sentence could still be correct, but it does require some context, such as:

> Where are the lobsters that we caught this morning?
>
> These are the lobsters.

Comment: Thank you! But is "These are the lobsters." wrong, or is it acceptable?

Comment: It is wrong in this context. It is not grammatically wrong though.